# Word Web js gives error Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error

Tags: office-js

Office js API gives the error "Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error" on calling the method document.properties.customProperties.getItemOrNullObject. This was working fine till 24 hours back so something has broken in the https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js file.

```
Word.run(function (context) { 
var myProperty = 
context.document.properties.customProperties.getItemOrNullObject("X"); 
context.load(myProperty); 
return context.sync() .then(function () { 
if (myProperty.isNullObject) { //Null property } 
else { //Not a null property } }) }) 
.catch(function (e) { console.log(e.message); 
})
```

The full text of the error is as below

Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: Cannot read property 'Y' of null
    at new c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:24:269960)
    at b.e.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:24:324485)
    at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:24:322590

Comment: I can't reproduce the "Uncaught (in promise)" part of the error, but I do get a RichApi.Error that tells me to load the `type` property of the object returned by `getItemOrNullObject` even though I'm not reading that property. Please see if your symptoms change if you load the object's `type` property before you sync.

Comment: Im not sure how and where I load the type property of the object returned by getItemOrNullObject. This is my function code for reading the property

Word.run(function (context) {
    var myProperty = context.document.properties.customProperties.getItemOrNullObject("X");
    context.load(myProperty);
    return context.sync()
      .then(function () {
        if (myProperty.isNullObject) {
          //Null property
        }
        else
 {
  //Not a null property
 }
      })
  })
  .catch(function (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    })

Comment: Please put your code in a code block in your original question so that it is readable. Your line `context.load(myProperty);` is equivalent to `myProperty.load();`. This is an empty `load` which means that you are loading all scalar properties including `type` anyway. I cannot reproduce your error when I'm loading `type` whether explicitly or with an empty load. Can you provide the full text of the error in your original post (as well as your code)?

Comment: Now I am also unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: This problem has recurred yet again and seems to be occurring intermittently with no defined pattern.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, and I can no longer reproduce the error I was getting that required me to load `type`. I'm on Office build 1904, 11514.20004. What build are you on?

Comment: Clicking on File -> About menu in Office online gives me a build number  16.0.11519.32652